# Python-Скрипт в cron не запускается

Tags: python, cron

```
* * * * * source ../var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/venvParser/bin/activate && python ../var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/main.py
@daily source ../var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/venvParser/bin/activate && python ../var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/daily_enter.py
```

В crontab -e набрал эти команды (первая должна выполнять скрипт ежеминутно, вторая - раз в день). Скрипты лежат в одной папке на сервере, если запускать без cron - работают без ошибок. Вместе с cron - как будто бы ничего и нет. Нет ни ошибок в терминале, ни результата работы программы (перед выходом в редакторе cron нажатие ctrl+'x', ctrl+'y' на "Save modified buffer?" пишу Y).

Answer (score 0):

```
source ../var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/venvParser/bin/activate && python ../var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/main.py
```

замени на

```
/var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/venvParser/bin/python /var/www/klaster_web__usr/data/www/klaster-web.ru/parser/main.py
```

И также со второй командой.